# Background-color inheritence in css

Tags: css, inheritance, background-color

I was wondering if there is possibility to create two divs with same color but with different opacity using inheritance.

As far as I found out, it is not possible. At least without the bug I guess.

If I set normal rgb color and give it opacity and inside div inherit background color and just set no opacity it wont't do the trick.

```css
#outside { background-color: #96B4DC; opacity: 0.5; }
#outside > * { opacity: 1; }
.inside { background-color: inherit; }
```

It would look like this : https://jsfiddle.net/s6pandof/5/

So I tried other options, easiest was for me the rgba. So I just set the color, inherited, and was thinking what to do more, but it surprised me.  There was no opacity in inner div. So it did the trick.

```css
#outside { background-color: rgba(150, 180, 220, 0.5); }
.inside { background-color: inherit; }
```

You could see it there : https://jsfiddle.net/s6pandof/6/

I tried it in Firefox 43.0 in Ubuntu as well as the same version in Android and Chrome 47.0.2526.83 in Android and every single one shows it this way.

My question is - Is this behaviour correct? Because it certainly doesn't seem to be. If it is not, is there any other possibility to make *inside* div inherit color from *outside* div, but set the background color to full opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-color:` alpha channel inheritance behaviour is correct.

One translucent `<div>` is overlapping another translucent `<div>`.

What you are seeing as the background of `div#inside` is the *combined* translucency.

See demonstration below:

```css
div {
position: relative;
}

p {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
}

div[id^='outside'] {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
}

div[id^='inside'] {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#outside1 {
background-color: rgba(150, 180, 220, 0.5);
}

#outside2 {
background-color: rgba(150, 180, 220, 0.4);
}

#outside3 {
background-color: rgba(150, 180, 220, 0.3);
}

#outside4 {
background-color: rgba(150, 180, 220, 0.2);
}

#outside5 {
background-color: rgba(150, 180, 220, 0.1);
}

#inside1, #inside2, #inside3, #inside4, #inside5 {
background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="outside1">
<p>Outside 1 (0.5)</p>
<div id="inside1"><p>Inside 1 (0.5 + 0.5)</p></div>
</div>

<div id="outside2">
<p>Outside 2 (0.4)</p>
<div id="inside2"><p>Inside 2 (0.4 + 0.4)</p></div>
</div>

<div id="outside3">
<p>Outside 3 (0.3)</p>
<div id="inside3"><p>Inside 3 (0.3 + 0.3)</p></div>
</div>

<div id="outside4">
<p>Outside 4 (0.2)</p>
<div id="inside4"><p>Inside 4 (0.2 + 0.2)</p></div>
</div>

<div id="outside5">
<p>Outside 5  (0.1)</p>
<div id="inside5"><p>Inside 5 (0.1 + 0.1)</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I understood the problem I had to set this answer as the correct one because of the snippet. It really explains anything one needs to know. Thanks.

Comment: Btw is there a special reason to use id inside with numbers? I guess the class would do the work the same for all insides and would be easier to look at.

Comment: Yes, `class` is absolutely fine. I used `id` only because `id` was used in the question.

Comment: Great, I'll switch it to class then, it would be more preffered option :)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is - Is this behaviour correct?

Sure: all you're doing is layering one semitransparent background color over another. Imagine layering a sheet of colored cellophane over another: the area where the sheets overlap appears more opaque. It's the same effect.

The `rgba(150, 180, 220, 0.5)` from the outside element is inherited by the inside element as you have specified, so you have two layers of that background color.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the correct behavior to me. Talking from experience, not from documentation.

I've tried it on my OSX Firefox 43 and Chrome 47.0.2526.106.

Comment: I guess correct behaviour should inherit the exact same color (with the same alpha). Not just show just pure rgb (without alpha).

Comment: Oh.. I kind off made myself ***.. I didn't realize that the inner div has as it's background the outer one so it is more full color. :(

Comment: @Polostor yep it's hard to debug with just the eye,adding 0.5 opacity and another 0.5 opacity makes it look opaque.